# Can't convert java Date default format

Tags: java, datetime-format, date

I'm trying to convert JSON to Java Object (transaction) and vice versa.
I keep getting this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Apr 28 02:41:11 IDT 2019"
```

at this line in my code below:

```
timeReceived = sdf.parse(json.get("timeReceived").toString());
```

even though I read the Date class description a lot of times and the format I 
used should match the date received.
Would appreciate some assistance. thanks!

My code:

```
    public Transaction convertJsonToTransaction(JSONObject json){
        UUID uuid= UUID.fromString(json.getAsString("uuid"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z 
yyyy");
        Date timeReceived= null;
        try {
            timeReceived = sdf.parse(json.get("timeReceived").toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String recipient =json.get("recipient").toString();
        Date timeSent= null;
        try {
            timeSent = sdf.parse(json.get("timeSent").toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String description=json.getAsString("description");
        return new Transaction(uuid, sender, timeReceived, recipient, 
timeSent, description);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        Transaction t = new Transaction(UUID.randomUUID(), "ms1", new 
Date(), "ms2", new Date(), "flow");
        net.minidev.json.JSONObject jo = t.convertTransactionToJson();
        System.out.println(((JSONObject) jo).toString());
        Transaction tr = t.convertJsonToTransaction(jo);
        System.out.println(tr.toString());
    }
```

Comment: What's your Locale set to? 'Sun'  will only be parsed properly if US-eng is used.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really small error in the date format: an extra space between date and hour placeholder `EEE MMM d  HH:mm:ss z yyyy`. Get rid of that and it works `EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy`

Comment: still does not work. but thanks for the correction. Got the same exception.

Comment: Your code is full of stuff that isn't related to the problem. Put in a trace statement that shows the string that you get back from the JSON. Write a little program to take that string (as a literal) and parse it. The whole thing should be less than 5 lines. If you can't figure it out from that, show THAT to us with your question. That is what is meant by a minimum example. Then we can help you with the date question, instead of wading through all the other stuff in your code.

Comment: But I pointed you directly to the problem. The problem is converting the JSON format string:
 {"sender":"ms1","recipient":"ms2","timeSent":"Sun Apr 28 05:36:38 IDT 2019","timeReceived":"Sun Apr 28 05:36:38 IDT 2019","description":"flow","uuid":"1ee602c2-4392-4d07-9a8e-6095af8e7fe3"}
into a Transaction. And it fails in the process of parsing the date pattern,
meaning something is wrong with my pattern (probably) or some weird thing that I can't see. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: @LimorHalevi You seem to have `yyyy` in a new-line after `z`, pls fix that. I have run the code and it works if you use `EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy` exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You have \n in regex. This thing happened many times with me. Just a suggestion when you found this type of issue go to any online tool to check special or hidden character in your string (Some time hidden char char will be there, you can not found them using your eyes.). Also one thing If you copy regex or any string used in program from any tool or online or any doc.., before pasting it in your code check if you copied any special char or hidden char. I normally use [this](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector) tool.

[image]

**Every thing else is correct It is working for me.**

[image]